# Remaining characters not decrementing while clicking the backpace or removing characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written keypress event to show the remaining characters for my text area control. It currently shows me the number of characters left while typing but does not decrement when clicking the backpace key or removing some characters from the text area. Could somebody tell me what the problem is

```
 $('#GeneralAgreementName').keypress(function () {

        if (this.value.length > 150) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("#remainingGeneralAgreementName").html("Remaining characters : " + (150 - this.value.length));
        }
    });
```

Comment: because you do not check to see if the key is going to actually add a character. Is there a reason you do not use maxlength?

Comment: @epascarello Why would he need to do that and how would it solve the issue?

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Because type 150 characters and you can not hit backspace and maxlength will prevent input....

Comment: @epascarello But how would checking if the key adds a character or not solve that?

Comment: Because you would know to return false or true.... backspace should NOT be false. Tab should not be false

Comment: And the code does not handle paste so the key check is useless for that check.

Comment: Should not `return false` in any case. And pasting also rules out your suggestion of checking what input the event will result in. It's simply not a practical solution to try to check what will be inserted. You would have to take modifier keys into consideration and such.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm hence why I said to use maxlength in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `keydown` event instead of `keypress`. Also, not sure why you are returning false from the event handler. Instead, add the maximum length to the textbox and just return the remaining characters.

```js
$('#GeneralAgreementName').keydown(function () {

        var charactersLeft = 150 - this.value.length;
        $("#remainingGeneralAgreementName").html("Remaining characters :" + (charactersLeft> 0 ? charactersLeft : 0));
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="GeneralAgreementName" maxlength="150" type="text">
<span id="remainingGeneralAgreementName"></span>
```

Comment: Still has same issue that OP states

Comment: type 150 characters and hit backspace, not going to delete anything. Also does not account for paste (different issue)

Comment: Understood, Other than copy paste it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use keydown function.

```js
 $('#GeneralAgreementName').keydown(function () {

        if (this.value.length > 150) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("#remainingGeneralAgreementName").html("Remaining characters : " + (150 -     this.value.length));
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="GeneralAgreementName" type="text">
<span id=remainingGeneralAgreementName></span>
```

Comment: Still has same exact issue as OP states

Comment: Needs to be `keyup` actually

Answer (score 0):

Don't `return false` when the length is over the limit, it prevents the textarea from getting any input at all.

Either:

- Truncate the value in the event handler if it's too long
- Prevent the data from being submitted if too long
- Set the `maxlength` attribute on the text field to make it impossible to input too many characters

...just don't `return false` in an event handler, ever.

Also, use `keyup` and `keydown` instead of `keypress`:

```
$('#GeneralAgreementName').on('keyup keydown', function () ...
```

Comment: $('#GeneralAgreementName').on('keyup keydown', function ()  {

        if (this.value.length > 150) {
            //return false;
         }
        else {
            $("#remainingGeneralAgreementName").html("Remaining characters : " + (150 - this.value.length));
        }
    });

Comment: I removed returning false but it allows me to enter charectors more than the required lenght. How do I set the max length. I am using mvc razor text area control. setting maxlength on that didnt help

Comment: @Tom I'm not familiar with Razor so I don't know. You can truncate the value yourself with `this.value = this.value.substring(0, 150);` (where you used to `return false`)

Answer (score 0):

HTML has a maxlength attribute so use it. That will keep the user from adding more characters, no need to deal with it yourself. Now you should listen for input event so it catches when the user types or pastes content in.

```js
$("[maxlength]").on("input", function () {
    var inp = $(this),
        sel = '[for="' + inp.attr('id') + '"].remaining',
        remaining = parseInt(inp.attr("maxlength")) - inp.val().length;
    $(sel).html(remaining + " characters remaining");    
}).trigger("input");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="test1">10</label><input type="textbox" maxlength="10" id="test1"><label for="test1" class="remaining"></label>
<br/>
<label for="test2">20</label><input type="textbox" maxlength="20" id="test2"><label for="test2" class="remaining"></label>
<br/>
<label for="test3">55</label><input type="textbox" maxlength="55" id="test3"><label for="test3" class="remaining"></label>
```